Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received
So I am trying to implement WebSocket using Socket IO in Express and Flutter.
Below is the server code
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New connection');
  socket.emit('message', 'Hello from server');
});


app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.send("Hello");
})
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});



Below is the package.json (if needed)
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5"
  }
}


Below is the flutter code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('WebSocket Example')),
        body: const WebSocketExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WebSocketExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebSocketExample({super.key});

  @override
  _WebSocketExampleState createState() => _WebSocketExampleState();
}

class _WebSocketExampleState extends State<WebSocketExample> {
  final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://192.168.119.36:3000'), // Use ws:// for WebSocket
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('WebSocket Example'),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: channel.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(
                snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : 'Waiting for messages...',
              );
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              channel.sink.add('Hello from Flutter');
            },
            child: const Text('Send Message'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Below is the pubspec.yaml
name: test
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: "none" 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.0-323.0.dev

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.0
  web_socket_channel: ^3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


The problem is that whenever the socket tries to connect to the server it provided with weired error
E/flutter (30549): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(40)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://192.168.119.36:3000

I have tested the app with library socket_io_client also, socket_io_client dont provide any error and simply disconnects. When I tried web_socket_channel library, it provides with this clue.
**PS: ** The functionality works, when I test in Linux, but it dont when I test in Android.
I have modified AndroidManifest.xml too.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:label="test"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

And below is the xml/network_security_config.xml in res folder
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.119.36</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Below is the flutter doctor --verbose result
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.24.0-1.0.pre.540, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.5.0-41-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.24.0-1.0.pre.540 on channel master at /home/paurush/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision dc052b869d (3 hours ago), 2024-08-10 09:39:25 -0400
    • Engine revision 0560465ecd
    • Dart version 3.6.0 (build 3.6.0-134.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.38.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/paurush/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/161/jbr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/161
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.94.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM M045F (mobile) • R9ZW90K3VVW • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34)
    • Linux (desktop)   • linux       • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.5.0-41-generic
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.114

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

**PS: ** The phone I am testing is connected via USB. And the desktop is getting network via USB Tethering of the same phone.
Below is the ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:d8:61:d8:25:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enxda24c5cb9006: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.119.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.119.255
        inet6 fe80::1580:e300:f60f:a04f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether da:24:c5:cb:90:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18483  bytes 14159680 (14.1 MB)
        RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 2
        TX packets 14996  bytes 4450124 (4.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 502810  bytes 1089343778 (1.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 502810  bytes 1089343778 (1.0 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lxcbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


And I have tested, the address http://192.168.119.36:3000 is accessible in browser in phone.
I would be glad if someone could help me solve the problem. Thanks
